# PHP not working

Tags: php, shared-hosting

I have a simple database with a few tables and I want to write some php script to fetch that data to my app. I deploy it on a shared host. Everything works fine, until today, I cant fetch data anymore, it always return HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error): An unexpected condition was encountered while the server was attempting to fulfill the request.
After that, I write a test.php like this

```
<?php>
echo 'bla bla bla';
<?>
```

And it dont run too. I mean I see a blank page.
After that, I try a test.html like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>PHP Test Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        PHP test page.
    <?php
      echo phpinfo();
    ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Only the "Php test page." appears in screen. 
I try byethost.com and oni.cc, the same problem appears. I dont see any .htaccess in htdocs folder. 
Please give some guidance.
Thank you in advance for your time and assisstance.

Comment: <?php
echo 'bla bla bla';
?>
your php tags are wrong

Comment: Make sure that PHP files use the `.php` extension and not `.html`. In the example above, you said you're using `test.html` but that run through the PHP interpreter.

Comment: Off the track, that's the reason purist hate PHP, anybody can mess up with code. PHP must have pointers to make things tough.

Comment: I'm Sorry, it's my typo mistakes. Code in test.php is right-syntax. With the test.html, I means html rendering is ok, but not php :(.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would check things like this:

- are your *.php* files accessable by webserver
- are there no messages in webserver's error logs
- are there no messages about server in system log
- if you have apache: is *.htaccess* file empty
- is webserver's config correct

Actually, in my experience,  500th error is mostly caused by endless loops or/and bad server config ( usually apache's .htaccess )

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
<?php echo 'bla bla bla'; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so you can run the phpinfo(); script, but some of your pages don't work
Did you try to debug?

try to set error_reporting to on, put this on top of the file before any includes:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_errors', E_ALL);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
?>
```

check for tag errors, like I said above `<?php echo 'bla bla bla'; ?>`
check your `.htaccess` file, maybe you did something worng there
check your control panel for any errors. any shared hosting should provide an control panel with process information. Maybe it's overloaded.